# why browser doesn't allow rendering local file

Tags: javascript, pdf

I was using PDF.js , good to know another plugin finally developed using JS. Another step toward that famous quote " if sth can be implemented using JS, eventually it will be implemented using JS".

I tried right away to open a local DEMO page, but it didn't work. and the introduction on PDF.js page indicated that some browser ( in my case: chrome ) don't allow open PDF file under URL file:///a.pdf

is this because of some security concerns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's using ajax to load the file, yes, it's the browser's interpretation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Some (most?) browsers don't allow ajax access to `file://` origins, even from documents loaded from `file://` origins.

Comment: except for starting a local server, is there anyway to work around this ?

Comment: @zinking: Just the usual things, which may not apply to that library. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), primarily. [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) doesn't apply, because there's no HTTP. But starting a local server is trivial.

Comment: @zinking: And actually, JSONP would only work if the callback name were static (because there's no server to interpret the `?callback=foo` parameter).